# lebesgue integral of $f(x^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I know that $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $0$, and $f\in L_1([0,1])$. How can one prove that $f(x^n)\in L_1([0,1])$, for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Note that, If $x\in [0,1]$ then $x^{n}\in [0,1]$.